# How do I get Paperclip to recognize custom processors instead of just pushing styles through to thumbnail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am not having any problem getting the custom processor to load, however when I try to call it from has_attached_file, paperclip ignores it, and instead just runs thumbnail.

**model**

```
  has_attached_file :file, 
                    :styles => { :web => "some input" }, 
                    :processors => [ :custom ],
                    :url => ":class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
                    :storage => :s3
```

As simple a processor as can be made just to show that the processor has been run

**processor.rb**

```
module Paperclip
  class Custom < Processor

    attr_accessor :input

    def initialize(file, options = {}, attachment = nil)
      super
      @basename = File.basename(file.path, File.extname(file.path))
    end

    def make
      dst = Tempfile.new([ @basename, 'jpg' ].compact.join("."))
      dst
    end
  end
end
```

But instead when I check the saved record it returns instance variables from thumbnail

> >record.file.styles

```
{:web=>
  #<Paperclip::Style:0x00000102f185d0
   @attachment=
    http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/model/id/base_name/file_name.jpg,
   @format=nil,
   @geometry="some_input",
   @name=:web,
   @other_args={}>}
```

I must be missing something in either writing the processor or calling it.  Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
 has_attached_file :file,
                        :styles => {
                         :my_super_style => {:geometry => "100x100#", :foo => "bar", :processors => [:custom]}

                        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you put in the right place?

```
lib/paperclip_processors/custom.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

:styles => { :web => "some input" }, 
                    :processors => [ :custom ],

should be:

:styles => { 
  :web => {:geometry => "some input", :processors => [:custom]},